# Convert from Angular2 beta 17 to @Angular RC2 but get this error _angular_platformBrowser.browserPlatform is not a function

Tags: angular

I have upgraded my project from angular2 beta 17 to @angular rc2 and now I get this error.

I had to add a system.config.js to get most of the errors to stop.

here is what my system.config.js looks like

```
 /**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular': '/js/angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    //'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
   // rxjs: { defaultExtension: false }
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
   // 'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
   // 'upgrade',
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  // No umd for router yet
  packages['@angular/router'] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

now Im just left with this error  Error: _angular_platformBrowser.browserPlatform is not a function. looking at the line number its system js thats throwing the error. not sure how to fix it.

Im pushing my typescript to a single file and loading it like this.

System.import("wwwroot/js/App/PageComponents/Order").catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });

also as a secondary question why does angular rc2 not use system.register for its modules anymore. is there another way to get them to load so I can combine the angular files because im not using angular as an spa and dont want to load all of my so when ever i go to a new page i get 60 or so calls to my components. in beta 17 i could combine them.

Comment: Just an fyi I can import the module with no errors without bootstrapping. the error happens when i bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this Updating to RC3 fixed this issue.